# Copy text from EditText to ListView

Tags: android

I want to know how to get text from an `EditText`, using a button, and place it in a `ListView`. I have tried this code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button send;
    EditText textBox;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendBtn);
        textBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textBox);

        EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textBox);
        String textBox = text.getText().toString();

        String arr[] = {};

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                                                                R.layout.activity_main, arr);

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        textBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {}
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: First off, I would personally not name the `String` and the `EditText` with the same variable name.

Comment: Assign the string to the array thats it.

Comment: try like this String arr[] = {textbox};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, set an `OnClickListener` for the Button. In that listener, grab the text from the `EditText` via `textBox.getText().toString()`. Next you want to update the the `ListView`'s list adapter with the newly selected text. There are a number of ways to do this

- Update the adapter and notify the `ListView` of the change
- Rebuilt the array of `Strings` and set the adapter for the `ListView` again

Comment: Thanks, I also had change the array to an ArrayList because the .add() method was not available for an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
Button send;
EditText textBox;

private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendBtn);
    textBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textBox);

    EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textBox);
    String textBox = text.getText().toString();

    String arr[] = {};

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
        R.layout.activity_main, arr);

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {
            adapter.add(textBox.getText().tostring());
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
        }

    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```